# A question about the Pigeonhole Principle and linear equations over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

This may be a bit trivial (apologies if it is), but I was wondering if there was an elementary way to compute the cardinality of the solution set in the following situation:

How many solutions would exist to the equation
$$2a + 2b + 4c + 4d = 8$$
if $a,b,c,d$ are distinguishable nonnegative integers?

---

Just to clarify, when I say "distinguishable", I mean that even if $a = b$, they represent different objects, and thus the solutions $(2,0,1,0)$, $(2,0,0,1)$, $(0,2,1,0)$, and $(0,2,0,1)$ are all distinct.

---

My real question, for which the trivial case above is just a motivating example, is:

More generally, if we are given $r$ strictly positive integers $p_1,\ldots,p_r$ (not necessarily distinct), how many solutions exist to the following equation for some moderately large $n\in\mathbb{N}$?
$$\sum_{i=1}^r p_i a_i = n$$
if $a_1,\ldots,a_r$ are distinguishable nonnegative integers?

---

I want to say that this is related to the pigeonhole principle, because using that, I was able to count exactly 14 such solutions in the trivial case of 4 nonnegative integers.  That being said, I'm not sure about the more general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple recursive algorithm to compute this. Let $N(p_1,\ldots,p_r,n)$ be the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^r p_ia_i=n$. Then
$$\begin{align}
N(p_1,n) &=\begin{cases}1&\text{if } p_1\mid j\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} \\
N(p_1,\ldots,p_r,n) &= \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/p_r\rfloor}N(p_1,\ldots,p_{r-1},n-p_rj)
\end{align}$$
While naive implementation of this algorithm has exponential runtime in $r$, using dynamic programming we can get the runtime down to $O(n^2r)$. In pseudocode:

> Initialize $N$ as an $r\times (n+1)$ array ($N[i][j]$ is the number of solutions to $\sum_{k=1}^i p_ka_k=j$)
>
> For $j = 0$ to $n$:
>
> $\;$ $N[1][j] = \begin{cases}1&\text{if } p_1\mid j\\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$
>
> For $i = 1$ to $r - 1$:
>
> $\;$ For $j = 0$ to $n$:
>
> $\;\;$ $N[i+1][j] = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor j/p_{i+1}\rfloor}N[i][j-p_{i+1}k]$
>
> Return $N[r][n]$

In Python:

> import numpy as np
>
> def numSolutions(p, n):
>
> N = np.zeros((len(p), n + 1))
>
> for j in range(n + 1):
>
> ```
>        if (j % p[0] == 0):
>
>                N[0,j] = 1
>
>        else:
>
>                N[0,j] = 0
> ```
>
> for i in range(len(p) - 1):
>
> ```
>        for j in range(n + 1):
>
>                for k in range(int(j/p[i+1]) + 1):
>
>                        N[i+1,j] += N[i,j-p[i+1]*k]
>
> return N[len(p)-1,n]
> ```

As a test, numSolutions([2,2,4,4],8) returns 14.

Comment: Is this assuming that each of the $p_i$ divide $n$?

Comment: @NicholasStull No.

Comment: @NicholasStull Whoops, I did indeed make that mistake. I'm fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions. First of all, you can divide through by 2:
$$
a + b + 2 c + 2 d = 4
$$
Now represent each variable by a term $z^a$, thus (disregarding the limit) for $a$ you get:
$$
1 + z + z^2 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Similarly for $b$, while $c$ and $d$ give:
$$
1 + z^2 + z^4 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1 - z^2}
$$
In all, you want the combinations that add up to 4:
\begin{align}
[z^4] &\frac{1}{(1 - z)^2 (1 - z^2)^2} \\
  &= [z^4] \left(
             \frac{1}{8 (1 + z)}
               + \frac{1}{16 (1 + z)^2}
               + \frac{1}{8 (1 - z)}
               + \frac{3}{16 (1 - z)^2}
               + \frac{1}{4 (1 - z)^3}
               + \frac{1}{4 (1 - z)^4}
           \right) \\
  &= \frac{1}{8} 
       + \frac{1}{16} \binom{-2}{4} 
       + \frac{1}{8} 
       + \frac{3}{16} \binom{-2}{4} (-1)^4
       + \frac{1}{4} \binom{-3}{4} (-1)^4
       + \frac{1}{4} \binom{-4}{4} (-1)^4 \\
  &= 14
\end{align}

Going to the general question posed at the end, it can be solved by this technique. But it rapidly gets *very* hairy. For small values of the sum it might be easier/faster to just try all posibilities (via backtracking). If you get handed lucky parameters (and the example certainly counts as such ;-) an analytic solution might be possible (in the example, it isn't too hard to derive a general formula giving the number of solutions for different sums).